# How to run a program in Atom Editor?

Tags: text-editor, atom-editor

I found [Atom](https://atom.io) editor as good free alternative to Sublime text editor. Not able to find a straightforward way to run a program in Atom editor. In my case, I am trying to run a java program. Please let me know if it's possible? If yes, please describe the steps to follow.

Comment: Solution is discussed in this similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014902/how-can-i-run-a-java-program-in-atom-editor/38106159#38106159

Comment: Use Script Package and then Ctrl+Shift+B to run the code. Output will be shown at bottom of ATOM. Script package is real cool stuff for ATOM.

Answer (score 47):

I find the Script package useful for this. You can download it [here](https://atom.io/packages/script).

Once installed you can run scripts in many languages directly from Atom using `cmd-i` on Mac or `shift-ctrl-b` on Windows or Linux.

Comment: I installed scripts package and tried to run Java program in my Windows machine. But got following error: 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Seems like script package needs some manual modification to run in Windows machine.

Comment: Is there any way to stop the started javascript(say with a timer)? Tried menu "Packages > Script > Stop Script" but it failed to work.

Comment: Also add Portable_Github & javac locations to Windows PATH

Comment: I can't install the package from the website. However I did it in atom inside. If anyone who is facing the same problem, go to "File => Settings => Install" and search for "script" and install

Answer (score 38):

1. Click on **Packages** --> **Commmand Palette** --> Select  **Toggle**.
2. Type **Install Packages and Themes**.
3. Search for **Script** and then install it.
4. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to run the code (on Mac)

Comment: I have installed the `Script`, and restart `Atom`, it works for me.

Comment: I think `atom-runner` is better because when using `Script` the code in current window moves a few lines horizontally. Maybe it's just a bit broken at the moment?

Comment: `Script` works sometimes for me. I notice when I run Ruby scripts it try's to run Rails. It's wonky that way. I've noticed that shutting it down and starting `Atom` back up works for a while. Too bad because I was starting to like working in `Atom`, with `VIM mode`. I always go back to `VIM` or `macvim`, I hope they fix `Script`. `Atom` has some nice features that I like over `ViM`.

Comment: I can't speak about Java running in `Atom` but it works great in `eclipse` or better in `IntelliJ IDEA` (best editor for Java imho)

Answer (score 4):

For `C`/`C++` programs there's very good package [gpp-compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler).

**Shortcuts:**

- To compile and run: <kbd>F5</kbd>
- To debug: <kbd>F6</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. How can we configure it to other keybinding ?

Comment: I'm not sure but it should be in the `file/settings/keybindings`.

Answer (score 4):

You can go settings, select packages and type [`atom-runner`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner) there if your browser can't open this link.

To run your code do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> if you're using `Windows` in `Atom`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to launch your program from the command line then you can run it from the [`platformio-ide-terminal`](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal) package's terminal. See `platformio-ide-terminal` provides an embedded terminal within the Atom text editor. So you can issue commands, including commands to run your Java program, from within it. To install this package you can use APM with the command:

```
$ apm install platformio-ide-terminal --no-confirm
```

Alternatively, you can install it from the command palette with:

- Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. I am assuming this is the appropriate keyboard shortcut for your platform, as you have dealt ith questions about Ubuntu in the past.
- Type **Install Packages and Themes**.
- Search for the `platformio-ide-terminal`.
- Install it.

Answer (score 2):

This package in Atom can run scripts.

[Atom script package](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner)

press Alt+X for the running script.
For running javascript you need to install 'node js'

Also pressing ctrl+shift+i in atom gives developer option like chrome

you can test javascript code side by side in atom editor.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this working properly on Windows, you need to manually set the path to the **JDK** (`...\jdk1.x.x_xx\bin`) in the system environment variables.

Comment: I added JDK path in environment variables. After, I get following error: javac: file not found: EnergySource.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: I spent sometime in editing CoffeScript file [grammars.coffee] of Script package.

Comment: Script for Java in Windows doesn't seem to append correct class path for the current Java file.

Comment: @Omkar I have encountered the same issue. To make it work either **1)** open _atom_ form the command line in the directory where the desired Java source file is located  or **2)** _right-click_ your Java source file and then try building - now it must work. In other words the problem seems to be that the **file path** to a file that you try to build is not correctly set. If you look in the `~\.atom\packages\script\lib\grammars.coffee` you will see that for building Java files on Windows it uses just **filename** without full path. I must say this is not what I expected, not convenient...

Comment: @informatik01 First option worked magically. Not sure to get second method. I don't see build option on right clicking source file in editor. But for clean solution, agree that `grammars.coffee` should consider full path for the file.

Comment: @Omkar Actually what I meant is right-click on the Java file **in the Windows Explorer** and choose _"Open with Atom"_. This way Atom gets the full path to your Java file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the runner in atom
Hit Ctrl+R (Alt+R on Win/Linux) to launch the runner for the active window.
Hit Ctrl+Shift+R (Alt+Shift+R on Win/Linux) to run the currently selected text in the active window.
Hit Ctrl+Shift+C to kill a currently running process.
Hit Escape to close the runner window

Answer (score 0):

You can run specific lines of script by highlighting them and clicking **shift + ctrl + b**

You can also use command line by going to the root folder and writing:
`$ node nameOfFile.js`