# How can I run a Java program in Atom editor?

Tags: atom-editor

I installed a scripts package to be able to run a Java program in Atom editor. But I'm still not able to run it. Getting the following error message:

> 'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file

What could be missing here?

I am using Windows 7. The same editor and same package runs on Ubuntu without any issues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Get GitHub Desktop from [GitHub Site](https://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHubSetup.exe). Run the installer to complete.
2. Get Atom Windows installer AtomSetup.exe from [Atom Site](https://atom.io/download/windows).
3. Once Atom installation completes, it launches.
4. From Package Menu, Navigate to "Settings View". Click on the sub menu item "Install Packages/ Themes".
5. Type "script" in the search text box, hit Enter.
6. Look for a package named "script" (run code in Atom) in the search result and click on install button in the result pane.
7. Once the package is installed, create a Java file and click Ctrl+Shift+B to run it.

P.S -

1. GitHub Desktop is a mandatory prerequisite for Windows environment.
2. Both of the installers are over 100 MB in size, so it can take some time.

Comment: @stendarr It automatically installs bash

Comment: For those using Mac, similar steps.  Use `COMMAND+i` to build.  You also need to install the JDK before building.

Comment: I am getting file not found in atom editor while i run with ctrl+shit+B

Comment: I fixed this error, by changing the CWD current working directory settings from the script package settings.Set CWD- to directory of the current script and that runs the program

Answer (score 1):

Main reason for this issue is scripts package is NOT built for cross-platform. "bash" won't be recognised on Windows. But we have following workarounds to make it work.

It works with following modifications:

- Ensure Java path is appended to PATH variable in environment variables.
- Since I am using git, I had installed [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) in my windows system.
- Set the git bash path in environment variables.

Now, able to run Java from atom editor. :)

As suggested in other forums, Cygwin could be other better alternative to get bash.