# Can I use Google Mobile Vision API in IntelliJ IDEA or Atom IDE?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, atom-editor

I am exploring the APIs provided by `Google`. Firstly, I was experimenting with `Google Cloud Vision API` with Python in PyCharm in order to try to perform Optical Character Recognition (OCR) with various texts.

So I wrote a basic program in Python in PyCharm which was calling this API, I gave to it as an input an image which included text e.g. the `image/photo` of an ice-cream bucket and then the output was the text written on this bucket.

Now I want to test the barcode scanner of `Google Mobile Vision API`. But`Google Mobile Vision API` is supported by Java and not Python so ideally I would like to call the `Google Mobile Vision API` in a Java program which calls this API, give as an input an `image/photo` of a barcode and take as an output the details saved in this barcode.

My question is if this can be (easily) done with `IntelliJ IDEA` or `Atom IDE` or if I should download Android Studio to do this simple task?

In other words, can I call easily call a mobile API in an IDE which is not specifically for mobile app development like `Android Studio` but it is for general java applications like `IntelliJ IDEA` or `Atom IDE`?

Comment: Ok no worries :)

Comment: It is my pleasure. Thanks for helping people with your knowledgeable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API is just that: a programming interface.

*Source* code that you want to compile against that API *only* needs to see that API in the class path.

In other words: the editor you are using absolutely doesn't matter here.

The only thing that matters is that you understand how to efficiently setup a "project" that includes the JARs required for that API.

Meaning: Android studio is a powerful but complex tool. You typically use it for developing mobile android apps.

Just writing a java class that uses some kind of external API is **not** something that requires Android Studio. Or do you think you would need to use Visual Studio when going to experiment with a JAR originating from Microsoft?!

On the part "what would be easier" - that *mainly* depends on your knowledge of the tool.

If somebody knows Android Studio by heart, creating the required project setup might take 1 minutes. The same person might need 5 or 10 minutes with IntelliJ.

Having said that: of course, IntelliJ is primarily designed to work as Java IDE. So setting up new projects and adding the required setup to use some JAR libraries is a straight forward task here. Atom on the other hand is even "simpler" - it basically allows you to skip that "project" part and work directly on hierarchies defined by folders.

In any case: you simply have to do a bit of research and see what works for you. Like following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014902/how-can-i-run-a-java-program-in-atom-editor) for atom, or this extensive [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html) for IntelliJ.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I agree. But my question finally is if this would this be as easy with `IntelliJ IDEA` or `Atom IDE` as it is with `Android Studio`?

Comment: @Universalis See my updates. We can't tell you how long you would need - as we have *no* idea about your current skills. If you know a tool, you get stuff done quickly. If you dont know the tool, you have to learn the tool first. Having said that, IntelliJ is an IDE primarily targeting Java development. It would be my first take here.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. Even though I ask more specifically the following: because `Google Mobile Vision API` is an API only for mobile apps then would it be easier to write a basic program and call it on `Android Studio` which an `Android IDE` or in `IntelliJ` which is a more general `Java IDE`? I think that it goes without saying that in questions like these you must assume that the user has equal experience in both of them. It is obvious that if a user knows an IDE better than other then she/he will probably be faster with the former one than with the latter one.

Comment: Haha, yes, surely upvoting.