# Frustrated with Atom.io invalid flag

Tags: java

Im using the package in atom called script. and I'm having trouble running my test code.

```
class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ]args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

```
error: invalid flag: G:\atom.projects\test
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

its keep saying this. what should I do?

Comment: hi shaine please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)  on how to ask questions correctly

Comment: Can you tell us **what exactly** you are trying to do and the **exact** command that you are execute to do it? It seems like you are passing a directory name to `javac` which is not one of the valid parameters to pass.

Comment: Hello, I just edited my question. sorry about that.

Comment: You need to edit your question add the *exact* command that you execute to run your program, as @JoachimSauer requested.

Comment: Check out the accepted answer in this post. Maybe you will find a solution there. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014902/how-can-i-run-a-java-program-in-atom-editor