# How can I run javascript file in atom code editor

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I was tried to load my JavaScript file in atom code editor with script plugin.but I failed again and again.now tell me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Which plugin? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

this seems duplicate and simple google will give u the answer.

[How to run a program in Atom Editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799522/how-to-run-a-program-in-atom-editor)

https://discuss.atom.io/t/beginner-question-how-to-preview-run-javascript-in-atom/46433